# How to make https certificate for local web server?

Tags: apache, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I make a web server run Apache - MySQL - PHP on Ubuntu (LAMP). My web server run local only, like web page config for wireless router,...

Then I want to make my webpage run https. And I follow this  [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04), it worked for me but just have a problem.

This certificate is self-signed, and Firefox still warning:

[image]

I don't know how to make https certificate for local web, it don't have live domain.